# dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-ef (>= 0.0.0)' for 'net5.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-ef (>= 0.0.0)' for 'net5.0/any'.
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

- You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
- A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
- The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
- You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator (>= 0.0.0)' for 'net5.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator (>= 0.0.0)' for 'net5.0/any'.
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

- You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
- A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
- The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
- You mistyped the name of the tool.

Answer (score 16):

`dotnet nuget list source` returned an empty list.
I guess you only run into this problem when you install dotnet without having visual studio installed on your machine that pre populates the official nuget site as source.

running `dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org` fixed the issue for me.

see https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/2044#issuecomment-910202971

Comment: Thanks, that was my issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run this command in pc without Visual Studio installation , you must add a nuget source first by this command :

```
dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Install it in your local project instead of globally, it will work for me. Execute the below commands one by one:

1. dotnet new tool-manifest (this will dotnet-tools.json file in your project)
2. dotnet tool install --local dotnet-ef --version 5.0.5
3. dotnet ef

Answer (score 0):

Try to install by including a version flag

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0
```